# Oracle: systimestamp at time zone error when selecting

Tags: sql, database, oracle, timezone

I am trying to create a select statement to get the time at the clients local timezone value.

Hence I wrote the query

```
select 
    systimestamp at time zone :TZ
from 
    DUAL;
```

which gives me the error

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 21
```

I have searched the net but I cannot find a way to use bind parameter to dynamically alter my query for the required timezone.

Thanks in advance.
All hail Oracle!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions007.htm), the time zone can be a literal or an expression; so it can't directly be a bind variable, but you can pass the variable into a function to turn it into an expression:

```
var TZ varchar2(10)
exec :TZ := 'America/New_York';

select 
    systimestamp at time zone trim(:TZ)
from 
    DUAL;

SYSTIMESTAMPATTIMEZONETRIM(:TZ)    
-----------------------------------
28-JAN-15 04.05.41.084443000 AMERIC 
A/NEW_YORK
```

Any benign function will do.

Although if you want the client's local time, you can use `at local` instead:

> If you specify AT LOCAL, then Oracle uses the current session time zone.

... or just use [`current_timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions045.htm#SQLRF00629) instead:

```
select current_timestamp from dual;
```

Comment: But. I hear that 'at local' clause will use the clients timezone setting. But what if he has set the wrong timezone. I would not want to take chance with that..

Comment: Then you should have a separate table where you administer the users timezones.

Comment: Yes. This is already implemented. The bind variable gets the value from the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    current_timestamp||':'||:TZ
from 
    DUAL;
```

Comment: I'm so sorry Mr.President but current_timestamp will always return time at the current timezone (client) who might have a wrong setting. I want to get the server time and display to client what his time is in his timezone. I appreciate your kind help.